# Rinohtype Sphinx restructured Text: Fixed Width Tables

Tags: python, python-sphinx, restructuredtext, rinohtype

Below is how we can get fixed-width, left-aligned tables in rst:

```
.. list-table:: Table Caption
    :width: 100%
    :align: left
```

But this doesn't seem to work in rinohtype. The alignment however i was able to get using my own stylesheet like below:

```
[table]
horizontal_align = LEFT
```

I don't understand how can i get a full-width table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will try and answer how i solved this, people with more knowledge on this can correct it later.

Based on [this issue](https://github.com/brechtm/rinohtype/issues/154), fixed-width problem seems to have been resolved.

According to the developer, this will be resolved in the stable release `v0.4.3`. However, it can also be solved currently by doing:

```sh
pip install git+https://github.com/brechtm/rinohtype.git
```

Comment: Correct. 0.5.0 is due to be released soon (skipping 0.4.3). In the meantime, you can download the [0.5.0-dev.0](https://github.com/brechtm/rinohtype/releases/tag/v0.5.0-dev.0) prerelease.